# start firefox extension without restart

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

i've created a firefox addon and working well. Now the question is how can i start
this addon without restart. i don't want restart disable/enable or install/uninstall process.

can any one help me in this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an extension to work without restarting Firefox, AFTER its installed?

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://adblockplus.org/blog/how-many-hacks-does-it-take-to-make-your-extension-install-without-a-restart

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you either have to make it a JetPack rather than an Add-On or you can read this guy's article:

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/09/15/adblock-dev-no-restart-firefox-extensions-possible/

Answer (score 1):

If you use this https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Jetpack you don't must to restart

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**, alas. I guess this is an ancient Mozilla design issue. Google Chrome can install extensions without restart.

Edit: As of 2012, Firefox can install some (but not all) extensions without restart. These extensions are badged 'no restart' in Mozilla's add-on store. Adblock Plus is one such extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/. I don't know the developers made that possible.

Answer (score 0):

From https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/faq

**How do I install add-ons without restarting Firefox?**

In Firefox, add-ons marked with "No restart required" can be installed without
restarting. These add-ons have been created using the [Add-on SDK](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/) or [bootstrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions). Other
add-ons will still require a restart before you can use them.

Comment: Good to know. Older add-ons had better migrate to the modern SDK.